# Change target runtime of ASP.NET Core Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm starting with ASP.NET Core Applications. I opened Visual Studio 2015, created a new ASP.NET CORE Web Application (.NET Framework) and just added the following on project.json:

```
"commands": {
    "http": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  }
```

Also I installed a nuget package for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener.

I published my application on file system, it created a .exe that runs a console and it works fine on my machine outside visual studio.

But I tried to run it on a Windows 7 SP1 x86 machine and got an error saying that it should be x86 program not x64.

When I created the publish profile it had an option "**target runtime**" but the only value available was "**Inferred Runtime(win7-x64)**". So here I guess is the problem. It was compiled in x64.

Is it possible to run the ASP.NET Core APP on Windows 7 x86?

I installed .netframework 4.5.2 on this VM. I tried to install .NET Core 1.0.0 -SDK Preview 2, but I got an error "0x80070001 - Wrong Function".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the project.json:

```
"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true,
"platform": "x86"
},
```